# Signature tool is not working with embedded signing

Tags: docusignapi

[Embededed Signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGbsE.png)

I created a template by Docusign Web Tool. I followed these steps, the embedded signing page is working but no signing tool was showing up. Even I added all tags/fields on the defined template.

I'm using Golang language and [this library](https://github.com/jfcote87/esign)

**1/ Create envelop using a template id**

```
var sv = envelopes.New(c.credential)
var env = &model.EnvelopeDefinition{
    Status:     "sent",
    TemplateID: c.config.DocusignTermTemplateID,
    TemplateRoles: []model.TemplateRole{
        {
            Email:            params.Email,
            Name:             params.Name,
            RoleName:         "signed",
            ClientUserID:     params.ClientID,
            DefaultRecipient: true,
        },
    },
}

envSummary, err := sv.Create(env).Do(context.Background())
if err != nil {
    c.CustomLogger.Error(err)
    return nil, err
}
```

**2/ Create embedded signing views.**

```
var sv = envelopes.New(c.credential)
var req = sv.ViewsCreateRecipient(params.EnvelopID, &model.RecipientViewRequest{
    ClientUserID:              params.ClientID,
    AuthenticationMethod:      "none",
    Email:                     params.Email,
    UserName:                  params.Name,
    XFrameOptions:             "allow_from",
    XFrameOptionsAllowFromURL: c.config.MerchantDashboardURL,
    ReturnURL:                 fmt.Sprintf("%s?client_id=%s", c.config.DocusignCallbackURL, params.ClientID),
})
resp, err := req.Do(context.Background())
if err != nil {
    return nil, eris.Wrap(err, err.Error())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We (DocuSign) can't provide support about an external library.

Some things to try:

1. **Edit** your question to add in the [API logs](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) that will show what was actually sent to DocuSign.
2. Don't use an iFrame for the signing ceremony and first try without the iFrame attributes.
3. You don't need the `DefaultRecipient: true` attribute on the Envelope create call.
4. First try creating the envelope for remote signing (signing via email). Remove the `clientUserId` setting to accomplish this. Check that the envelope is delivered properly, looks right, etc.
   Then add in the embedded sending. This way you can determine if the problem is with the envelope create call or the envelope recipient view call.

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of this is that the template roles aren't aligned between your API call and the template on the server. To confirm, you'll want to check your server template and confirm that the Role Name is `signed` (as it is in your API call) and that the signer role does not have a pre-filled name and email (as pre-filling the name/email blocks populating those values through the API).